# Command line switches for Netop Remote Control version 9.0 (NGstw32.exe)

Tags: command-line

Would anyone by any chance have the command line switches for Netop Remote Control version 9.0 (NGstw32.exe)? I've contacted Netop support but they no longer support this version, and I can't update because it's a a work tool at my job.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try one of the user manuals from [Remote Control User’s Manual for version 9.0](http://kb.netop.com/article.php?id=115)?

Comment: [Netop Remote Control Administrator’s Guide](http://kb.netop.com/article.php?id=110)

Comment: @DavidPostill  I've indeed found the switches, thanks! I was on the site, don't know how I missed it...

Answer (score 1):

#### What are the command line switches for Netop Remote Control version 9.0?

> I've contacted Netop support but they no longer support this version.

You can still find documentation for version 9.0 on the net op site:

- User Manuals: [Remote Control User’s Manual for version 9.0](http://kb.netop.com/article.php?id=115)
- Administrator Manual: [Netop Remote Control Administrator’s Guide](http://kb.netop.com/article.php?id=110)